# Solution Deployment : Error occurred for solution solution.wsp - Error: The copying of this file failed: Telerik.Web.Design.dll

Tags: deployment, solution-package, telerik

I am getting below error while deploying solution.

In Central Admin

> Some of the files failed to copy during deployment of the solution.

In ULS

> Solution Deployment : Error occurred for solution solution.wsp -
>   Error: The copying of this file failed: Telerik.Web.Design.dll.

I am getting simile error for other third party dll as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are couple of reasons for this error.

- if you have antivirus installed on the server, then make sure it is not blocking those dll to deploy.
- make sure SharePoint timer and Admin services running on all servers
- May be restart the time service and admin service on all sever, some time timer service lock the files on the server.
- also check if you package files are not locked at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But none of the solution worked for me. If i delete files from web application's bin folder before deployment it worked. If file is present then it throws this exception. Also this exception is not being thrown on all machine. I could not understand how can i check "package files are not locked at all"

Comment: r u deploying via powershell then can use force parameter...riight click on the files see the properties n see if it is locked...also recyle timer service on that server?

Comment: I am using Force parameter as well as I am restarting timer service before installing solution. Sorry but I couldn't find anything which says Lock in property window of DLL.

Comment: what you doing, upgrade the service or reInstall it? are the Dlls also aviable on other servers?

Comment: I am deploying solution on single server farm.

Comment: what powershell you using? if you are using upgrade then file but if you installing it without removing it then it will be issue

Comment: I am following this sequence Uninstall-SPSolution, Remove-SPSolution, Add-SPSolution, Install-SPSolution and it fails at Install-SPSolution

Comment: after removing the files still exist in the bin folder, right>

Comment: Humm... after going through the log i found another error which is being occured during retraction. "Solution Deployment : Error - Retraction failed for package.wsp Target http://site/. Error - Portal : I/O error occurred.  Portal : Error: The removal of this file failed: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\site\bin\Telerik.Web.Design.dll."

Comment: that's it, when you removed the package it was not properly removed. that's why you getting the error at deployment. Now you can manually delete the files or try to remove it using the -force switch or contact to telerik. I think finally we nail it down.Now you have root cause

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot. We found the root cause but will have to look into it further to see why its not being deleted. I am already using -Force with Remove-SPSolution. Looks like file is being used by some or other process. I also try to see if this file is being used somewhere with ProcessExplorer but no luck. One thing I forgot to mention that the size of this package is 24 MB and it only dumps third party dll and reusable components in either bin or gac. Will that cause any issue? Is there a way where I can see which process is using this file?

Comment: Try to reset timer job before removing solution then try agaain.as it is telerik  solu..may check with any known issue

Comment: Btw, if I help u and this post, please up vote as well as marked answer

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping IIS and the Timer service on all servers before deploying:
iisreset /stop
net stop sptimerv4

Then reverse after:
iisreset /start
net start sptimerv4

Those are the two  most likely EXEs that will lock the Telerik DLLs. The SharePoint install process *should* clear the locks for w3wp.exe at least, but in practice we have seen that sometimes it doesn't. This seems more common when the DLL is a dependency for the primary WSP output. Not sure why, just an observation.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint it is ?